# Using node-foreman under supervisord in production

Tags: node.js, express, supervisord, foreman

I got so comfortable using [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) with Rails applications on Heroku and elsewhere that I seek out clones when I work with other languages; I use [honcho](https://github.com/nickstenning/honcho) for Python/Django and I've been using [node-foreman](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman) to develop an Express project. I'm ready to move that Express project into production (Ubuntu 14.04 on Amazon EC2) and am having troubles.

I can launch and run the project using `nf start` just fine, but the [node-foreman docs](https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman) say not to daemonize such a thing, but rather that I should generate a `supervisord` conf file using something like

```
nf export --type supervisord --user ubuntu
```

This works, and the results look correct, but the Express application won't launch as it seems unable to pick up the values from the environment values. `supervisord` is successfully running a Django-based RESTful API server on the same host. Sensitive values replaced, `foreman-web-1.conf` looks like:

```
[program:foreman-web-1]
command=npm start
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopsignal=QUIT
stdout_logfile=/var/log/foreman-web-1.stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/foreman-web-1.stderr.log
user=ubuntu
directory=/home/sites/site-root
environment=PORT="3000",API_HOST="api.example.com",USER="user",PASS="password",SES_USER="ses_user",SES_PASS="ses_pass",SES_SMTP_HOST="email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",SES_SMTP_PORT="587",RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY="site_key",RECAPTCHA_SECRET="secret",FEEDBACK="someone@example.com",PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games",PORT="3000",FOREMAN_WORKER_NAME="web.1"
```

but the stderr.log contains

```
/home/sites/site-root/node_modules/express-recaptcha/lib/express-recaptcha.js:27
  if (!this.site_key) throw new Error('site_key is required');
                            ^
Error: site_key is required
```

which indicates that the `RECAPTCHA_` environment variables aren't being seen.

I can't figure out if the problem is with `supervisord` or my Express application or with `node-foreman` and I'd appreciate any insights or recommendations. I suspect it's something simple and obvious, but this is the first time I've tried to get all these pieces working together in a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it takes a lot of work to let `supervisord` know you're serious about changing settings. [This serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/479754/104187) helped me see the light.